# Beginners doubt: calculating probability of one qubit based on other in a 2 qubit system

Tags: quantum-state

This is going to look like homework because it is from a self-inflected Coursera course. I have already found the answer by trial and error but I want to clear my logic. (Coz I'm not getting sleep otherwise and I can't ask the question in Coursera without revealing too much and ruining the quiz for others.)

[image]

Instead of doing the long math here I used the online calculator: here’s a [link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/complex-numbers-calculator/%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B%5Cleft%7C-%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(1%2B%5Csqrt%7B3%7Di%5Cright)%7D%7B4%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright%7C%5E%7B2%7D%2B%5Cleft%7C%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(1-%5Csqrt%7B3%7Di%5Cright)%7D%7B4%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright%7C%5E%7B2%7D%2B%5Cleft%7C-%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(1-%5Csqrt%7B3%7Di%5Cright)%7D%7B4%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright%7C%5E%7B2%7D%2B%5Cleft%7C-%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(1%2B%5Csqrt%7B3%7Di%5Cright)%7D%7B4%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright%7C%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7D):

[image]

Once again online calculator to help : [Link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/complex-numbers-calculator/%5Cleft%7C%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1%2B%5Csqrt%7B3%7Di%7D%7B4%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1-%5Csqrt%7B3%7Di%7D%7B4%7D%5Cright)%5Cright%7C%5E%7B2%7D):

The result comes out as 3/4 but the expected answer is set as 1/2.
Can anyone help? I might be missing something very simple.

#### Edit

**The complete solution:**

$$\begin{aligned}|\phi| = {(1+ \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle +|-\rangle)|0\rangle+{(1- \sqrt{3}i)\over 4\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle + |-\rangle)|1\rangle \\ + {(1- \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle-|-\rangle)|0\rangle+{(1+ \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle - |-\rangle)|1\rangle\end{aligned}$$

By dropping the $|+\rangle$ combinations we are left with

$$\begin{aligned}|\phi| = {(1+ \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|0\rangle-{(1- \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}}\rangle|1\rangle+{(1- \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|0\rangle-{(1+ \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|1\rangle\end{aligned}$$

This is where I was wrong to not solve it even further.

$$|\phi| = ({(1+ \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}}-{(1- \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}})|-\rangle|0\rangle+({(1- \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}}-{(1+ \sqrt{3}i) \over 4\sqrt{2}})|-\rangle|1\rangle$$

$$|\phi| = {\sqrt{3}i \over 2\sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|0\rangle-{\sqrt{3}i \over 2\sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|1\rangle$$

Next, we normalize this.

$$|\phi| = {({\sqrt{3}i \over 2\sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|0\rangle-{\sqrt{3}i \over 2\sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|1\rangle) \over \sqrt {{\left|\sqrt{3}i \over 2\sqrt{2}\right|^2}+{\left|\sqrt{3}i \over 2\sqrt{2}\right|^2}}}$$

$$|\phi| = {2\sqrt{3} \over 3} . {\sqrt{3}i \over 2\sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|0\rangle-{2\sqrt{3} \over 3}.{\sqrt{3}i \over 2\sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|1\rangle)$$

$$|\phi| = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|0\rangle-{1 \over \sqrt{2}}|-\rangle|1\rangle)$$

Hence the probably of second qubit: $P(|0\rangle)$ when the first qubit is $|-\rangle$ is :

$$|\phi| = {\left ({1 \over \sqrt{2}}\right )}^2 = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Hey @S4nd33p! While the image format provided works, it's very preferable to use LaTeX in the future! If you have time, I'd recommend updating the question to be formatted in LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i'll work on it. It does feel a bit stupid not being able to copy-paste the code. In the mean time, ctrl+/- to zoom in/out may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line immediately before Step 2, you have like terms that can be combined. Combine these, *then* renormalize the vector.

Recognize that your misstep lies in the properties of the amplitude. Generally, for some $a, b$ components and $x, y$ separation:

$$
|a + bi|^2 \neq |x + yi|^2 + |(a - x) + (b - y)i|^2
$$

In this case, the like terms aren't combined, so we're combining the probabilities of the individual terms, which doesn't hold.

Comment: Both the answer above helped me to look at my mistake but thanks for pointing out the exact step where I was going wrong. It worked perfect and I will type-out the complete solution in a minute to help anyone else equally hopeless with this like me.(hopefully in latex, if not then as an image - I'm a noob in latex.. sorry)..

Answer (score 1):

There is no long math, and you need not online calculators. When you simply omit $|+\rangle$ state of the first qubit after the measurement, the resulting 2-qubit state $|\Phi\rangle$ is *unnormalized*. You just need to factor out the state $|-\rangle$ of the first qubit and *normalize* the remaining state of the second qubit before obtaining the final answer.